# How do I scrape something after JS has changed the DOM?

Tags: javascript, ruby, screen-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize

I'm using Mechanize, although I'm open to Nokogiri if Mechanize can't do it.

I'd like to scrape the page after all the scripts have loaded as opposed to beforehand.

How might I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nokogiri and Mechanize are not full web browsers and do not run JavaScript in a browser-model DOM. You want to use something like [Watir](http://watir.com/) or [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/) which allow you to use Ruby to control an actual web browser.

Comment: If you want a real JavaScript-enabled browser to automate but without a visible window, try a headless browser like (capybara-webkit)[https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit] or (PhantomJS)[http://phantomjs.org/] (there are others as well).

Comment: @echristopherson Thanks; those are [capybara-webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit) and [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) respectively (fixed markup links).

Answer (score 6):

I think a good option is something like this with Nokogiri, Watir, and PhantomJs:

`b = Watir::Browser.new(:phantomjs)`

`b.goto URL`

`doc = Nokogiri::HTML(b.html)`

The resulting doc will be from when after the scripts have been loaded. And phantomjs is nice because there is no need to load a browser.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to watir-webdriver and capybara-webkit, [celerity](http://celerity.rubyforge.org/) is a good option although it is jruby only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about mechanize or nokogiri so I can't comment specifically on them.  However, the issue of getting JavaScript after it's been modified is one I believe can only be solved with more JavaScript.  In order to get the newly generated HTML you would need to get the .innerHTML of the document element.  This can be tricky since you would have to inject js into a page.

The only way I know of to accomplish this is to write a FireFox plugin.  With a plugin you can run JavaScript on a page even though it's not your page.  Sorry I'm not more help, I hope that this helps to put you on the right path.

If you're interested in plug-ins this is one place to start:http://anthonystechblog.wordpress.com/category/internet/firefox/

Comment: Instead of rolling your own plugin from scratch, Greasemonkey could probably do it.